# Video not playing in Flat list react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, video, flatlist

I'm using Swiper-FlatList, but same issue on both either a flat list or Swiper-FlatList. Even local videos from the device is not playing and same with the uri. single video is playing perfectly.

Render video smoothly like in instagram reels
please help...

Comment: show me your code

Comment: my flat list
<SwiperFlatList
        data={posts}
        renderItem={VideoItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item?.id}
        onChangeIndex={handleChangeIndexValue}
        vertical={true}
        ListEmptyComponent={!homeLoading && EmptyComponent}
        refreshing={homeLoading}
        onRefresh={onRefresh}
        onEndReached={onEndReached}
        ListFooterComponent={renderListFooterComponent}/>

Comment: i was able to find issue, basically onChangeIndex is not working properly when index is changed and the video remains paused. but how to fix this?

Comment: show me the code